How Read-Through caching strategy can ensure data consistency?(with additional questions)
I'm studying Cache Read strategies.
I found two strategies are generally used.

Look-Aside strategy.
Read-Through strategy.

I understood difference of Look-Aside and Read-Through is "Who has Responsibility for Caching".
Many articles are saying
A: "If use Read-Through strategy, Data consistency problems can be avoided by always synchronizing data between cache and DB."
and
B: "With the Read-Through strategy, you will always get a cache miss the first time you request data."
But, I can't understand A and B.
I have two question.

Q1: In A, If there is data in the cache, it is returned as is. How can data consistency be guaranteed?

Q2: In B, even if the Look-Aside strategy is applied, won't a cache miss occur when data is first requested? Why is B an important point in the Read-Through strategy?


What i treid?

I looked up cache writing strategies.

In this process, I understood the Write Back strategy, Write Through strategy, and Write Around strategy.


